# How to declare a vector of parameters in .ned file

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to declare a vector in .ned file in INET.

I tried in following way but got syntax error.

```
double new[] @unit(s) = default({0.01s, 0.02s, 0.05s, 0.08s, 0.003s});
```

Would anyone please suggest me the correct syntax?

I'm using OMNET++ 5.5.1 with INET 4 framework.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't declare a vector of parameters in NED. Only modules may be declared as vector.
However, you may achieve similar effect using string.
In NED declare the string that pretends a vector:

```
string times = default("0.01s 0.02s 0.05s 0.08s 0.003s");
```

Then add in C++ class of your module, for example in `initialize()` that code:

```
std::vector<std::string> timesStr = cStringTokenizer(par("times")).asVector();
std::vector<simtime_t> timesPar;  
for (auto i : timesStr) {
    simtime_t t = simtime_t::parse(i.c_str());
    timesPar.push_back(t);
}

EV << "Read " << timesPar.size() << " parameters from \"times\"" << std::endl;
// show all read values
for (int j=0; j<timesPar.size(); ++j) {
   EV << timesPar[j] << "; ";
}
```

After executing `timesPar` contains the array of parameters from `times`.

Notes:

- In this example a space is the delimiter, but it is possible to use any other character as delimiter in [cStringTokenizer](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cStringTokenizer.html).
- `new` is a keyword in C++ therefore I suggest using other name for parameter and variable.

Comment: Jerzy, here ```timesPar``` is displaying array size. I have two questions : 1) How to display the values? 2) How  to access a particular element of this vector by inputting an index number, where the index number is a variable. For example, times[m] = value; where m is the index number. So, if m=1, i will get 0.01. Many thanks

Comment: `timesPar` is just a `std::vector` so you may obtain any values using for example `simtime_t x = timesPar[0];` or `int m = 1; simtime_t x = timesPar[m];`.

Comment: Jerzy, is it possible to declare a matrix using string? If yes, can you say the syntax of it? For example, a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is possible to declare a matrix using string. I encourage you to ask a new question with an example of matrix parameters you need to read - according to SO rules one question should resolve on issue only.

Answer (score 2):

In OMNeT++ 5.x, there are no vector parameters and you can work around this only using strings containing space separated values. On the other hand, **OMNeT++ 6 Preview 7** introduced `object` parameter type, which can accept JSON syntax arrays and maps. So this is valid:

```
 object array = [ 1s, 1+1, 3.14157m, true, false, "Hello", 'World' ];
```

And you can access this parameter as a `cValueArray` type from the C++ code.

Comment: Many thanks Rudi. Both of the answers are very helpful.

Comment: Do you know how can we get this parameters from ini file?