# Update parameter value in XML format

Tags: omnet++

I have parameters stored in an XML file. Below is a sample of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <terminal id="A">
      <terminalCapacity>3</terminalCapacity>
      <terminalMembers id="1">
            <memberID>0001</memberID>
            <memberCapacity>2</memberCapacity>
      </terminalMembers>
    </terminal>
    <terminal id="B">
      <terminalCapacity>4</terminalCapacity>
      <terminalMembers id="1">
          <memberID>0002</memberID>
          <memberCapacity>1</memberCapacity>
      </terminalMembers>
      <terminalMembers id="2">
          <memberID>0003</memberID>
          <memberCapacity>3</memberCapacity>
      </terminalMembers>
    </terminal>
</root>
```

Each terminalID is associated to a type of `simpleModule` found in my NED file. The idea is to programmatically update these values throughout the simulation run. The current logic revolves around getting the current parameters in XML format and update the `memberCapacity` field.

From the Omnet [cPar](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cXMLElement.html) and [cXMLElement](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cXMLElement.html) documentation, I tried using the `par("moduleParameter").xmlValue()->getXML()` function, but this returns the XML as a string. I also tried using the `getAttribute()` function, but to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. `par("moduleParameter").xmlValue()` will give you the in memory object tree of the XML document, but that is not meant for modification. Your XML file seems to be just a hierarchical structure and modules and their parameters can mirror that exactly. There is absolutely no reason to reinvent the wheel when you can mirror that with INI file parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I needed to be able to add and remove "terminalMembers" fields throughout the simulation run. Ended up using the INI file parameters and the object parameter described in your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688923/9980065) and it works perfectly!